# Muestra Undefined en el select, cuando se recorre un array desde js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select, undefined

Tengo el array obtenido desde un json, por `console.log(filas)`, muestra esto :

```
[
  {
    "respuesta": 1,
    "consultorio": "2027",
    "nombre_consultorio": "ANESTESIOLOGIA"
  },
  {
    "respuesta": 1,
    "consultorio": "4045",
    "nombre_consultorio": "BIENESTAR FETAL"
  }
]
```

pero cuando lo intento mostrar un `select` desde `js`, el ajax, lo tengo asi :
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "consultorios.php",
data: { 'fecha': lc_fecha },
beforeSend: function() {

```
    },
    success: function(filas) {
        $("#mostrar_espera").html("");
        for (var e = 0; e < filas.length; e++) {
            $("#slc_consultorio").append('<option id="' + filas[e]["consultorio"] + '"  >' + filas[e]["nombre_consultorio"] + '</option>');
        };
    }
});
```

y muestra el `select` pero en el valor : **undefined**

Algo falta?

Comment: Tu error no es reproducible, tu código funciona perfectamente.

Comment: una ves ejecutado la consulta el resultado lo tengo asi:  success: function(filas) {
            for (var e = 0; e < filas.length; e++) {
                $("#slc_consultorio").append('<option id="' + filas[e]["consultorio"] + '"  >' + filas[e]["nombre_consultorio"] + '</option>');
            };  algo falta?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo a la pregunta. En los comentarios es ilegible.

Comment: ya lo agregue en el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener algo malo en algún otro lado, acabo de probar el código que compartes y funciona perfectamente, los datos del select cargan correctamente y no hay ningun valor `undefined`, se muestran claramente los nombres de los consultorios.
Aqui te dejo la prueba:

```js
const filas = [
  {
    "respuesta": 1,
    "consultorio": "2027",
    "nombre_consultorio": "ANESTESIOLOGIA"
  },
  {
    "respuesta": 1,
    "consultorio": "4045",
    "nombre_consultorio": "BIENESTAR FETAL"
  }
];

for (var e = 0; e < filas.length; e++) {
    $("#slc_consultorio").append('<option id="' +
        filas[e]["consultorio"] + '"  >' +
        filas[e]["nombre_consultorio"] + '</option>');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slc_consultorio"></select>
```

Comment: En tu ejemplo, veo que has asignado el nombre de una variable filas como constante,   esa varibale lo obtengo de :  success: function(filas) { ..... }, como lo puedo ser compatible?

Comment: es irrelevante... solo pon el ciclo `for` dentro de esa funcion (sin la declaracion de const)

Answer (score 1):

debido a que el problema persistia, ya lo pude resolver de esta manera :

```
jsondecoded = $.parseJSON(filas);
     $.each(jsondecoded, function(index, value) {
          $("#slc_consultorio").append('<option id="' + value.consultorio + '"  >' + value.nombre_consultorio + '</option>');

        });
```

gracias a todos los amigos por sus aportes...